Given argument of list[int] | list[str], can't I be sure that the list is list[int] if element [0] is int, and vice versa?
I have a python script and trying to add type hints to the code, Following is the sample code (without type hints the code works) using mypy.
values_int: list[int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
values_str: list[str] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

def bar(*, x: list[int]) -> bool:
    # processing
    return True

def baz(*, y: list[str]) -> bool:
    # processing
    return True

def foo(*, values: list[int] | list[str]) -> bool:
    status: bool = False

    if isinstance(values[0], int):
        x: list[int] = values
        status = bar(x=x)

    elif isinstance(values[0], str):
        # case-1
        # status = baz(y=values)

        # case-2
        y: list[str] = values
        status = baz(y=y)

    return status

foo(values=values_str)

Errors for:
# case-1
#  error: Argument "y" to "baz" has incompatible type "list[int] | list[str]"; expected "list[str]"

# case-2
#  error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "list[int] | list[str]", variable has type "list[str]")


@tripleee, the list always have single datatype either all int or all str

I can see that that's what you want it to mean, but mypy wants guarantees. (I think. In the end I deleted my comment at least until I can investigate this some more on my own.)

Type hints PEP 695 Type Parameter Syntax are supported in Python 3.12 but not (yet) in mypy

isinstance(a[b], ...) is not (yet) supported as a type narrowing construct. For what it's worth, Pyright also doesn't support it.
Perhaps you want a custom TypeIs:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
from typing_extensions import TypeIs

def is_list_of_ints(v: list[Any]) -> TypeIs[list[int]]:
  return isinstance(v[0], int)

def is_list_of_strs(v: list[Any]) -> TypeIs[list[str]]:
  return isinstance(v[0], int)

def foo(*, values: list[int] | list[str]) -> None:
    reveal_type(values)      # list[int] | list[str]
    
    if is_list_of_ints(values):
        reveal_type(values)  # list[int]
        bar(x=values)        # fine

    elif is_list_of_strs(values):
        reveal_type(values)  # list[str]
        baz(y=values)        # fine

Note that Mypy 1.10.0 has a bug with TypeIs: it incorrectly determines the second conditional branch to be unreachable:
def foo(*, values: list[int] | list[str]) -> None:
    reveal_type(values)      # list[int] | list[str]
    
    if is_list_of_ints(values):
        reveal_type(values)  # list[int]
        bar(x=values)        # fine

    elif is_list_of_strs(values):
        reveal_type(values)  # error: Statement is unreachable
        baz(y=values)

A workaround is to use TypeGuard instead:
(playground)
from typing import TypeGuard

def is_list_of_ints(v: list[Any]) -> TypeGuard[list[int]]:
  return isinstance(v[0], int)

def is_list_of_strs(v: list[Any]) -> TypeGuard[list[str]]:
  return isinstance(v[0], int)

The difference between TypeIs and TypeGuard is explained in PEP 742.
